# How do we modify and access the value of a parameter?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a case as follows. I am working on merging 2 xml files. I compare a particular type of node in both files and check if their some particular attribute is same. If that attrib is same, I merge that node and if it does not, I copy the node of file one. Please see the logic below

```
for-each(file1/nodes)
   boolean variable var set to false
   for-each (file2/nodes)
      when(some_condition)
      var = true
   /for-each
   if(var = false)
      do-something
/for-each
```

My problem is that I am unable to set and retain this variable. As I am very new to xslt, I would need help to accomplish this using xslt.

```
<xslt:for-each select="$file1_coverage/packages/package">
<xslt:variable name="file1_package_name" select="@name" />
<!-- I want to declare a boolean variable and set it false-->
<xslt:for-each select="$file2_coverage/packages/package">
    <xslt:variable name="file2_package_name" select="@name" />
    <xslt:choose>
        <xslt:when test="$file1_package_name=$file2_package_name">
            <!-- Set the boolean variable to true-->
            <package>
                <xslt:attribute name="branch-rate">
                    <xslt:value-of select="(($file1_package_branch_rate * $file1_package_branch_total) + ($file2_package_branch_rate * $file2_package_branch_total)) div ($file1_package_branch_total + $file2_package_branch_total)" />
                </xslt:attribute>
            </package>
        </xslt:when>
</xslt:for-each>
<xslt:when test="boolean Variable is false">                                
        <package>
            <xslt:copy-of select="$file1_package/@*" />
            <xslt:copy-of select="$file1_package/*" />
        </package>
</xslt:when>
</xslt:for-each>
```

Comment: Could you post some simple sample input and expected output? Also what version of XSLT?

Comment: Added sample code. My requirements are in the comments

Comment: Consider to post an XML input sample and the corresponding output sample you want to create with XSLT, then people here can help you with a proper XSLT approach to solve that. I am afraid posting some imperative pseudo code does not allow us to provide concrete XSLT code as XSLT is not an imperative language. And as you seem to be working with two input documents please also tell us whether you are working with XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 as 2.0 has better support for easy cross-referencing with different input docs (e.g. `key('key-name', 'key-value', documentNode)`).

Comment: I just need help to declare, initailize and modify a boolean variable inside an xslt.

Comment: @Messiah, XSLT is a functional language. This means, besides other things, that a variable's value, once defined, cannot be modified.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes, I understand. But is there, by any chance, any way to do that by using a param(parameter)

Comment: @Messiah, When you call or apply a template, you can always pass to it an `xsl:param` with the same name and with a new value -- like this: `<xsl:with-param name="pyourParam" select="$pyourParam + 1234"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `booleanVariable` goes out of scope after the first `xsl:when` -- its scope is only inside the `xsl:when`

**The correct and useful way to define a boolean variable is**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vboolVar">
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="some-condition">true</xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then use this variable anywhere in the scope of its parent element.

**Of course, one can define the same just by**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vboolVar" select="some-condition"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a boolean variable. Use instead two loops. In the first you handle all matching entries and in the second one the entries not match.

```
<xslt:for-each select="$file1_coverage/packages/package">
    <xslt:variable name="file1_package_name" select="@name" />
    <!-- handle all matching entries -->
    <xslt:for-each select="$file2_coverage/packages/package">
            <xslt:variable name="file2_package_name" select="@name" />
        <xslt:choose>
                <xslt:when test="$file1_package_name=$file2_package_name">
                    <package>
                        <xslt:attribute name="branch-rate">
                                <xslt:value-of select="(($file1_package_branch_rate * $file1_package_branch_total) + ($file2_package_branch_rate * $file2_package_branch_total)) div    
                            ($file1_package_branch_total + $file2_package_branch_total)" />
                    </xslt:attribute>
                </package>
            </xslt:when>
        <xslt:choose>
    </xslt:for-each>
    <!-- … and now the not matching entries -->
    <xslt:for-each select="$file2_coverage/packages/package">
            <xslt:variable name="file2_package_name" select="@name" />
        <xslt:choose>
                <xslt:when test="not ($file1_package_name=$file2_package_name)">
                    <package>
                    <xslt:copy-of select="$file1_package/@*" />
                      <xslt:copy-of select="$file1_package/*" />
                </package>
            </xslt:when>
        <xslt:choose>
    </xslt:for-each>
</xslt:for-each>
```